# Nodemailer: Greeting never received

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, npm

When trying to send email within Node using Nodemailer (https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer), the call to the `sendMail` of the Nodemailer transporter is raising the error `Greeting never received` when using in conjunction with an Ethereal test email account.

I have tried using both a "callback approach" and also an "async/await" approach, but the same error is thrown in both scenarios. Both examples are pretty much straight from the working examples in the Nodemailer documentation. Maybe I'm missing something simple? :)

Here is the "callback approach" code that is producing the error:

```
it('can send email with a dynamic test account', done => {
    nodemailer.createTestAccount((err, account) => {
        const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            host: 'smtp.ethereal.email',
            port: 587,
            auth: {
                user: account.user, // generated ethereal user
                pass: account.pass // generated ethereal password
            }
        });

        const mailOptions = {
            from: '"Fred Foo " <foo@example.com>', // sender address
            to: 'bar@example.com, baz@example.com', // list of receivers
            subject: 'Hello ✔', // Subject line
            text: 'Hello world?', // plain text body
            html: '<b>Hello world?</b>' // html body
        };

        // send mail with defined transport object
        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
            if (error) {
                return console.log(error);
            }
            console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);
            console.log('Preview URL: %s', nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));
            // Message sent: <b658f8ca-6296-ccf4-8306-87d57a0b4321@example.com>
            // Preview URL: https://ethereal.email/message/WaQKMgKddxQDoou...

            done();
        });
    });
}).timeout(10000);
```

And here is the stacktrace of the error:

```
{ Error: Greeting never received
    at SMTPConnection._formatError (/Users/<username>/projects/personal/learning-tests/javascript/nodemailer/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:606:19)
    at SMTPConnection._onError (/Users/<username>/projects/personal/learning-tests/javascript/nodemailer/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:579:20)
    at Timeout._greetingTimeout.setTimeout (/Users/<username>/projects/personal/learning-tests/javascript/nodemailer/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:520:22)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:498:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:323:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:290:5) code: 'ETIMEDOUT', command: 'CONN' }
```

And some additional info:

- node version: `8.11.2`
- nodemailer version: `4.6.4`
- operating system: `OSX version 10.12.6`

Answer (score 24):

In my case I needed to set the `secure` key to `true` on the `transporter` object and then it worked.

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: "mail.hostname.com",
        port: 465,
        secure: true, // true for 465, false for other ports
        auth: {
            user: 'user@hostname.com', // generated ethereal user
            pass: 'password', // generated ethereal password
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 6):

In my case, when I have changed port 586 to 587, then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Check your internet connection probably its down .
below is an example with [Etheral Email](https://ethereal.email/) with typescript

```
import * as nodemailer from "nodemailer";

export const sendEmail = async (recipient: string, url: string, linkText: string) => {
  nodemailer.createTestAccount((err, account) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: account.smtp.host,
      port: account.smtp.port,
      secure: account.smtp.secure,
      auth: {
        user: account.user,
        pass: account.pass
      }
    });

    const message = {
      from: "Sender Name <sender@example.com>",
      to: `Recipient <${recipient}>`,
      subject: "Nodemailer is unicode friendly ✔",
      text: "Hello to myself!",
      html: `
        <html>
        <body>
        <p>Testing sparkpost API</p>
        <a href="${url}">${linkText}</a>
        </body>
        </html>`
    };

    transporter.sendMail(message, (err, info) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Error occurred. " + err.message);
      }

      console.log("Message sent: %s", info.messageId);
      // Preview only available when sending through an Ethereal account
      console.log("Preview URL: %s", nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));
    });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` in `/etc/postfix/main.cf` was causing this issue.

Changed it to:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
   permit_mynetworks,
   permit_sasl_authenticated,
   reject_unauth_destination,
   check_policy_service unix:private/policyd-spf
```

and now it works!

Answer (score 0):

```
Error: "Error occurred. Greeting never received"
```

It was occuring for me when i was connecting to a vpn/secure wifi network provided by IT company , when i change the data network it was resolved for me.

Answer (score -1):

I am using Nestjs Framework and SendGrid as an email sevice provider and by default, SendGrid uses opportunistic TLS encryption for outbound emails. This prevents cybercriminals from reading the contents of an email while it’s in transit, known as a man-in-the-middle attack.You can explore about it more in the sendgird official blog
[https://sendgrid.com/blog/what-is-email-encryption/#:~:text=By%20default%2C%20SendGrid%20uses%20opportunistic,server%20accepts%20an%20inbound%20TLSv1.](https://sendgrid.com/blog/what-is-email-encryption/#:%7E:text=By%20default%2C%20SendGrid%20uses%20opportunistic,server%20accepts%20an%20inbound%20TLSv1.)

Change secure from 'false' to the 'true' in your .env file as you need to send email securely.

```
#Mail Constant
MAIL_HOST=smtp.sendgrid.net
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_SECURE=true

#Mail credentials

MAIL_USERNAME=apikey
MAIL_PASSWORD= <yourAPIkey>
```

and fetch the value of secure form your environment variables like this :

```
MailerModule.forRootAsync({
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => {
        return {
          transport: {
            host: configService.get('MAIL_HOST'),
            port: +configService.get('MAIL_PORT'),
            secure: configService.get('MAIL_SECURE') === 'true',
            auth: {
              user: configService.get('MAIL_USERNAME'),
              pass: configService.get('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
            },
          },
          defaults: {
            from: '<sendgrid_from_email_address>',
          },
        };
      },
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'config.mail.service',
  port: 8000,
  auth: {
    user: 'config.mail.username',
    pass: 'config.mail.password'
  }
});

module.exports = {

  activationsMail: function (req) {
    // setup email data with unicode symbols
    const mailOptions = {
      from: '"Ecommerce" <noreply@ecommerce.com>', // sender address
      to: req.body.email, // list of receivers
      subject: 'Ecommerce Account Activate', // Subject line
      html: '<div>Please <a href="' + req.headers.host + 'user/activate/' + req.code + '" target="__new">click here</a> to active your account.</div>' // html body
    };
    console.log('PORT', req.headers.host);

    // send mail with defined transport object
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
      if (error) {
        console.log('Email Error', error);
      } else {
        console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
      }
    })
  }
};
```

Comment: This is a code-only answer, which is not considered good practice in StackOverflow. Please `edit` to elaborate. Explain what this code does and how it helps to solve the original problem.

Answer (score -4):

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: config.mail.service,
  port: 8000,
  auth: {
    user: config.mail.username,
    pass: config.mail.password
  }
});

module.exports = {

  activationsMail: function (req, data) {
    // setup email data with unicode symbols
    const link = 'http://' + req.headers.host + '/user/activate/' + data.verifyCode;
    console.log('CODE :', data.verifyCode);
    const mailOptions = {
      from: '"Ecommerce" <noreply@ecommerce.com>', // sender address
      to: req.body.email, // list of receivers
      subject: 'Please confirm your Email account', // Subject line
      html: '\n\n' + 'Please Click here to verify <a href=' + link + '> Click here</a>'
    };
    //console.log('PORT', req.headers.host);

    // send mail with defined transport object
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
      if (error) {
        console.log('Email Error', error);
      } else {
        // callback(true);
        console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
      }
    })
  };
```

Comment: This is a code-only answer, which is not considered good practice in StackOverflow. Please elaborate and explain what this code does and how it helps to solve the original problem.

Comment: Using this code we can able to send mail. And with the help of HTML body we will write mail body.

Comment: Hi @HirenGevariya. Your above comment is not the explanation for your code. Your answer will be more helpful if you could add an explanation to it.