# Nodemailer Error Error: Greeting never received after updating nodemailer

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I recently update nodemailer, and I can no longer send messages.
I get the following error:  (node:62368) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Greeting never received.

I tried with the code:

```
 const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
host: 'smtp.ethereal.email',
port: 587,
secure: false,
rejectUnauthorized: true,
auth: {
    user: ethereal_username,
    pass: ethereal_password
}
```

I could send e-mails before updating to the newer version.
I tried withpit secure and rejecteUnauthorized, I also tried using gmail and mailtrap.
Nothing seems to be working.

Thank you.

Comment: this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50493831/nodemailer-greeting-never-received